# SQL Server 2008, recovering RAM memory

Tags: sql-server-2008, memory

Is there a way to reset the memory used by SQL Server 2008 R2 to what it would be if I restarted the service? (but I don't want to restart the service)

I tried using

```
Checkpoint -- Write dirty pages to disk
DBCC FreeProcCache -- Clear entire proc cache
DBCC DropCleanBuffers -- Clear entire data cache
```

but I always free up more memory by restarting the service.

Comment: what would the purpose of this be? SQL server tries to allocate as much contiguous memory as possible and manage it by itself. You get to decide at config time, whether you want `dynamic` or `static` amount of memory allocated to the SQL service process.Maybe if you can expound on the purpose, we can try to help with a solution.

Comment: you don't need to free up sql server's memory.

Comment: It turns out that the max mem setting does not include the memory used by SQLCLR and I use SQLCLR heavily. That's why the memory used by SQLServer can be bigger than max men.

Comment: @"you don't need to free up sql server's memory" : 

Oh yes you do.  We also have SQL Server 2008 running on a Windows Server 2008 machine, and, despite setting the "max server memory (MB)" value to 6Gb, within an hour or so, it always uses up almost all of the machine's memory... way over 6Gb.

The only way to release it is to restart the server or run "EXEC sp_configure 'max server memory (MB)'"  again.

If we don't do that, the machine is soon crippled. Even Symantec's LiveUpdate can bring the CPU to 100%, as it can't get any memory.

We're desperate... has anyone a permanent solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the excellent webcast [Mission-Critical SQLCLR](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/DevDays/DevDays-2011-Netherlands/Devdays052), which explains that the max mem setting in SQL Server does not include memory used by SQLCLR.
To find out how much memory is actually used by SQLCLR, you can run:

```
select * 
from sys.dm_os_memory_objects 
where [type] like '%CLR%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sp_configure procedure to change the max server memory (MB) configuration setting. SQL Server will adjust to the new setting without a restart.

You should configure this setting with the desired value then leave it if you find that SQL Server is hogging memory needed by other processes.